# Remote access to MySQL on my web server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I am hosting my own web server and am trying to access my MySQL database from my laptop (not the server). On my laptop I have added the following to the config.inc.php file:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'nick';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I have created, on the server, a user named "nick" with all grants. I have tried a LOT of different configurations of the code above and I just cannot connect remotely.

The host IP is the IP of my router that is using a DNS linking it to the domain name, I would imagine it is the same host needed here. I am port forwarding 8080 for my website and using a port 80 rerout with the DNS. I get this error when trying to connect to the server from my laptop:

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Somebody please help, I do not want to spend forever on this :/ I'm supposed to be working on the website, not the MySQL remote connection haha!

Comment: Clarify please: the machine you are trying to connect to is the one _behind_ the router, or outside the router?  Are you forwarding 3306 through the router?  Is the target machine's firewall open?  What grants have you actually created? Does the ISP you're working with block 3306 entirely (some do)?

Comment: Is the target machine setup to accept inbound connections to 3306 in `my.cnf` (that is, is it bound to an external address, and `skip-networking` not enabled)? Setting up a connection to a remote database has lots of failure points.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski both my laptop and the server machine are on the same LAN using the same router. My ISP does not block 3306. I am not forwarding 3306, I will try that. I am running it with Wampserver so there is no my.cnf, my.ini though, do you know how to configure it in my.ini?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I tried forwarding the port and it still did not work :/ I just want to be able to edit the databases without connecting a monitor, mouse, and keyboard to the server every time I need to make a change haha!

Comment: Just fixed it. I had to add an exception in my Windows Firewall for port 3306 as well as forward it.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You can turn your solution in to an answer and select it as the best answer -- you won't get reputation for it but the question will show as solved so others can benefit from your findings in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Firewall create an exception for port 3306. Make sure that the port is also being forwarded.

Comment: If you are the client, would you have to make sure that the port is forwarded from your end, or is this something for the owner of the server to do?

Comment: This is from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL runs on port 3306, it sholdn't be blocked. It wasn't for me.

Then make sure that your mysql allows connections from the outside.

Just edit your my.cnf file

- If you are using Debian Linux file is located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf location.
- If you are using Red Hat Linux/Fedora/Centos Linux file is located at /etc/my.cnf location.
- If you are using FreeBSD you need to create a file /var/db/mysql/my.cnf location.

  $ nano my.cnf

Go down until you find [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 65.55.55.2
# skip-networking
```

Modify "bind-address" to the ip of your server so that it listens on it (it is default to localhost).

Comment: I am using Windows XP for the server and it is running a WAMPserver. It does not have a my.cnf but a my.ini, any suggestions?